# Data parallelism, task parallelism or none?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parallel.foreach

I am using ASP.Net Core 1.x to host Web APIs. One of my APIs receives JSON data as input. The input is in form of a list of Newtonsoft JSON's JObject. 
The API must validate the input JSON data.
The validation is of two kinds - 
One that does validates for any constraint like the JSON field's value is within given range (for numbers) or matches a regular expression pattern, etc. 
The second type of validation checks if the given JSON field value is one of the valid values as it exits in the database.

My current implementation roughly iterates over each JObject and then each of the JProperty and then does the validation with optimization to do a batch query for the second type of validation.

I am looking for suggestion on how to improve this sequential validation.

Since the first type of validation is completely a CPU bounded operation, I am looking over using `Parallel.ForEach` to process each object's validation in parallel. I see the validations of each object as independent operation.

However I read from the given book [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449367565_sampler.pdf)-

> ...in general, parallel programming on the server would work against the
>   built-in parallelism and would not provide any real benefit.

This makes me confuse. Should I not go for parallel processing? What are other options for me?

Update: (based on comments below)
The JSON size is currently set to 2kb - 20Kb. Set of load tests ran on this API with 20 users hitting the API concurrently, reduces the performance. The API then starts taking more than 3s to complete. As of today, the input json size is maxed to 20 kb, but if we get further algorithmic improvements, I would like to increase the max JSON size from 20Kb.
However the above update which talks about the performance requirement for API under load, is separate from original question that - whether data parallelism or task parallelism could be used with ASP.Net Core Web API.

Comment: Is you API for completely dynamic data? Otherwise, there's no real reason for using JObject instead of a model with DataAnnotations and using the builtin validations

Comment: That should be a really huge json for you to get any benefit from parallelizing it's validation in forms of range checks and regular exprsesions.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, yes the API accepts a dynamic data. So there is no class defined.

Comment: Before you start trying to improve the performance you should measure the performance. How long is it taking to perform the validation currently? How is the time split between the two phases? How many database accesses does it do? Are there any simpler performance improvements you can do before you try to add parallelism? How many simultaneous requests are there against this API? If you parallelize one are you harming the others?

Comment: @Evk, yes the input size of the json data could be something in range of 2kb - 20kb

Comment: Well that's not big. How long does it take now to validate it (excluding database validation)? i'd expect few milliseconds.

Comment: @IanMercer I ran some load test simulating a load of 20 users each sending input of varying input size and found that at max load the total wall clock time for the API is more than 3 seconds. I am targetting to get it under a second or so. The performance profiling points to validation taking most of the time, the DB time was well  below to 250-400 ms. For a single user scenario, it was well under a second.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us the relevant code.

Comment: So in this scenario (20 concurrent users and a CPU-bound step (with, I assume, no locking or other contention)), parallelizing one user's request will simply steal CPU cycles from the other users' requests: it's not going to increase throughput and may well decrease it. But, like others, I'm curious how some simple numeric checks and a few RegEx's can possibly take that long to evaluate. Maybe post an example of your comparison and RegEx code.